# Sort collection and sort remains in place when adding to collection?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

When I get a collection back from the service tier, I create an ArrayCollection and apply a sort. When I add an item to the collection later on, the sort is still in place? It seems to be the case. I thought I was only sorting it once, not applying a sort that will stick???

Here is the method for adding an item:

```
private function onAddNewClick():void
        {
            var fileTemplate:FileTemplateDetailDTO = new FileTemplateDetailDTO();   
            fileTemplate.fileTemplateId = 0;
            fileTemplate.fileTmpltDtlId = 0;
            fileTemplate.createdBy = appModel.userName;

            newFieldsDp.addItem( fileTemplate );

            this.fieldsGridEmpty.rowCount = newFieldsDp.length + 1;
            totalCount = newFieldsDp.length;
            this.fieldsGridEmpty.scrollToIndex( totalCount );
        }
```

And here is what I'm trying now for when the data comes back from the service:

```
for each( var dto:FileTemplateCompositeDTO in coll ){
            dto.templateHistory = createHistoryColl( dto.details );
            var sortedArray:ArrayCollection = sortDetails( dto.details );
            sortedArray.sort = null;
            var freshArray:Array = sortedArray.toArray();
            dto.details.source = freshArray;
            model.fileTemplateComposites.addItem( FileTemplateCompositeDTO( dto ) );
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to do a one time sort:

```
var array:Array = yourArrayCollection.toArray():
array.sortOn("SomePropertyAvailableInEachItem", Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);
yourArrayCollection.refresh();
```

Since you're not sorting the underlying Array, and not the collection.

Comment: This came closest to exactly what I was looking for. The only thing is that I would like to sort on more than 1 property, which you can do with the Sort object. I'll have to find some way. But thank you for your help.

Comment: if you use the [Array's sort function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort()), you can specify your own compare function which can take multiple properties into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

No. You should call `myCollection.refresh()` every time it is changed. But you can listen for [`collectionChange` event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#event%3acollectionChange) and call refresh from there:

```
    private function collectionChangeHandler(event:CollectionEvent):void
    {
        if (event.kind == CollectionEventKind.ADD || event.kind == CollectionEventKind.REMOVE ||
            event.kind == CollectionEventKind.REPLACE || event.kind == CollectionEventKind.MOVE || event.kind == CollectionEventKind.UPDATE)
        {
            ArrayCollection(event.currentTarget).refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is that I only want it sorted once. By the time I add something to it, I want the sort to be gone.

Comment: I've added a sample how to do it with event. You can extend collection with that functionality without any problem.

Comment: I don't understand, you're not refreshing the collection twice?  Why do you need to refresh at all? he just wants a sort.

Comment: @J_A_X I thought @fumeng wants to keep collection sorted after adding every new item :)

Comment: Nope. I want to sort it as soon as the data comes back and then remove the sort (though still displaying its initial sort) before I even add an item. Not a problem, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The sort of an `ArrayCollection` will remain linked to it. You can try to set the `sort` attribute to null after the initial sort and refresh, but I'm not 100% sure that a following `refresh()` will keep the elements order (although it should).

Another approach: after applying the initial sort to your collection, you can call its `toArray()` method to obtain a (sorted) array, then just create a new `ArrayCollection` passing that array as its source in the constructor. Note that `ArrayCollection` is really just a wrapper on array, so the `toArray()` and the construction of a new `ArrayCollection` for an existing array should not be heavy operations.

Comment: The call to refresh() after null does not keep the elements in order. However, your 2nd suggestion I tried but it appears that the sort is kept on the Array after using toArray() and applying that a source to a new ArrayCollection. I'm going to keep working on it because it seems that it could work with some tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

A `Sort` on an `ArrayCollection` is an object itself. When you assign the `Sort` object to the sort property on the `ArrayCollection`, it remains assigned until you remove it manually. To remove it, just set the `sort` property on your `ArrayCollection` to `null` after you call `refresh()`.

```
myArrayCollection.sort = mySort;
myArrayCollection.refresh();
myArrayCollection.sort = null;
```

Now any time you call refresh() on the ArrayCollection, the `sort` is no longer in place.

Comment: I do that and when I try and add an item in the collection, I get a: Error #1006: value is not a function. error.

Comment: @fumeng How are you adding the item? Do you have a code example?