# AS3/Flex apply sort to ArrayCollection only once

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, sorting, air, flex4

I've got an `ArrayCollection` that serves as a dataProvider for a list.

The collection stores objects of type `MyObject`:

```
public class MyObject {
    public var myMap:Dictionary;
}
```

`myMap`stores key-value pairs, the key being an `integer`, the values are Strings.

So far for the constraints. What I want to do now is to sort the collection based on fields of the map.

Using a the `ArrayCollection`'s `sort` function with my own `compareFunction` does work. This is how I've implemented it:

```
    var key:int = 15;
    var sort:Sort = new Sort();
    sort.compareFunction = fidSort;
    myCollection.sort = sort;
    myCollection.refresh();

    private function fidSort(a:Object, b:Object, fields:Array = null):int {
        if(a.myMap[key].fieldValue == b.myMap[key].fieldValue) {
            return 0;
        } else if(a.myMap[key].fieldValue > b.myMap[key].fieldValue) {
            return 1;
        } else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

As I said, that does work for the sake of sorting. However, naturally the sort (being a property of the collection) remains on the collection unless specifically removed from it, which means that every time a value in the map of `MyObject` changes, it will get sorted according the comparefunction.

What I need is to apply the sort exactly once, what happens afterwards with the map values shouldn't change the collections sorting.

I've tried things like disabling autoupdate on the colleciton (naturally that won't work as the collection doesn't get any updates any more (well it does, but they are cached only)).
After that I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6537338/1069487) post about sorting the underlying array.
However, that doesn't seem to work with the map, as I do get a compile error saying that the `myMap[key].fieldValue` couldn't be found on `MyObject`.

So yes, I'm kinda lost in space here. If someone has a clue how to achieve this, very basic task really, please let me know.

Cheers!

Comment: Might want to try [Array.sort()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort()) it accepts a compare function like the one you've shown above. Or show the code you used when you tried `Aray.sortOn()` -- these should both allow you to sort that underlying array in the collection. Maybe the compile error when using `sortOn()` could be solved by something like this: `a.myMap[key]["fieldValue"]` instead of `a.myMap[key].fieldValue`.

Comment: @SunilD., thanks so far. I've tried using `Array.sort(fidSort);` already, and the compare function executes correctly, however the `ArrayCollection` isn't getting sorted, even though I called `refresh` on it. As for the `a.myMap[key]["fieldValue"]`, that doesn't work either. But I'm fine if the compare function on the array would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, and for the sakes of completeness, I'd like to answer this question myself.

As said before, using `myCollection.toArray().sort(fidSort)` didn't work completely. The array made in this step has indeed been sorted, the collection, however, didn't get the sort, even though `refresh()` has been called.

To fix this, instead of creating a new array from the collection, we need to directly use the collection's source (which is an array of course) and sort that array;

```
  collection.source.sort(fidSort);
  collection.refresh();
```

Since we are still only sorting the array and not applying the `Sort` to the collection itself, the collection is sorted only once, regardless of the updates to it's data.

Edit: Just for kicks, restoring the original item positions isn't possible out of the box when sorting the `collection`'s underlying array like it can be done when applying a sort on an `ArrayCollection` directly and setting it to null to restore the positions.
Simple solution is to cache the array item indices beforehand.